# How to run TeX documents through Grammarly?

Tags: text, markup, proofreading

I have many articles that I'd like to run through Grammarly. The problem is, they are all written with TeX markup throughout (ConTeXt specifically, but I'm hoping for a more generic solution that works with almost any of the TeX varieties).

If I run the file with the markup into Grammarly, Grammarly has trouble parsing the information. For instance, it thinks words after `}` must be the start of a new sentence, so it adjusts the capitalization and complains of a missing subject.

Taking the code out of the document is not hard, with a few runs of `sed`, but then after I've edited the document in Grammarly, all of that TeX markup needs to go back in, and sometimes I have lots and lots of it, with custom information (such as citations), that need to go back where they were.

Is there any tool that lets me extract the TeX markup, getting just the plain text of the document, then put that TeX markup all back where it was, after having run it through a proofreading tool like Grammarly?

Comment: Seems like manual copy/paste from the PDF could be an option ([quora](https://www.quora.com/Can-Grammarly-check-a-PDF-for-grammar-and-or-spelling-issues) - link mainly explains steps in Grammarly Premium/GoogleDocs/Chrome/PDF tool chain).

Comment: I asked Grammarly if they were thinking about integration with Overleaf, and they answered the standard "not now, but we're thinking about it" (more or less 6 months ago).  My University have a license with them, and I find that copy-n-paste from source is most of the time sufficient (in real document markup is normally minimal) --- then I use manual patching...

Comment: You can also explore `pdftotext`.

Comment: The search results of https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Grammarly%22 suggest that it is not possible at the moment. I have no idea how Grammarly works, but maybe you can choose 'ignore all' or something similar for specific code-related issues like '}'?

Answer (score 2):

Detex is maybe what you need : https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats#Convert_to_plain_text